# How can I query a joints sao (secondary axis world orientation)? Maya Python

Tags: python, axis, maya

I want to query the `sao` of one joint so I can assign it to another.
In this case I have managed to get the `oj` of the `LowArm` via `.jot`, and I'm trying to do something similar with `sao`.

```
mc.joint ('L_Hand_JNT', e=1, oj=mc.getAttr ('L_LowArm_JNT.jot'), sao='yup', zso=1)
```

Any help or advice would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out a way to get the result that i want, and that is to create a shadingNode that has an Enum named after the orient joint command used for a specific joint, in this case the shoulder.

```
if mc.objExists ('L_ShoulderOrient_NODE'): mc.delete ('L_ShoulderOrient_NODE')
mc.shadingNode ('transform', au=1, n='L_ShoulderOrient_NODE')
mc.addAttr ('L_ShoulderOrient_NODE', ln='jointOrient', at='enum', en='yup', k=1)
```

The above I've added at the create joints stage after which i used the script below:

```
if mc.ls ('L_Shoulder_JNT', sl=1):
    if mc.objExists ('L_ShoulderOrient_NODE.jointOrient'): mc.deleteAttr ('L_ShoulderOrient_NODE.jointOrient')
    mc.addAttr ('L_ShoulderOrient_NODE', ln='jointOrient', at='enum', en=WOB3 + WOB4, k=1)
```

WOB3 is the up or down based on the orient choice for the primary and secondary orient, WOB4 is the UP or DOWN as chosen from the orient joint menu.
The mc.ls ('L_Shoulder_JNT', sl=1), makes sure that this script is only in effect when this specfic joint is selected and changed.

I was then able to run this script:

```
JOX = mc.attributeQuery( 'jointOrient', n='L_ShoulderOrient_NODE', le=1 )
mc.joint ('L_Hand_JNT', e=1, oj=mc.getAttr ('L_LowArm_JNT.jot'), sao=JOX[0], zso=1)
```

Which brought all the elements together, supplying an up/down vector for newly created joints, based on that chosen at random by the user.

All that's now left is to delete the node at the end of the process.
If Anyone thinks up an alternate way of getting the upvector of a pre-existing joint and applying it as above please let me know below!

Many thanks,
Adam

Comment: If you only need the orientation to within the limits of up-down-left-right, you can use the matrix to get the local axes of the matrix and then get the dot product the secondary axis against the main world axes.  A dot of 1 will be aligned and -1 will be opposite; 0 is at right angles.  The largest absolute value of the dots will be the secondary axis.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think joints have an 'sao' attribute: the flag is there to allow you to specify the secondary axis when aligning a joint because a single orientation does not provide enough information for maya to lay out the joint:  like an aim constraint you need to tell maya how to solve for a given target since there an infinite number of valid solutions.

You can, however, get each 'axis' of the joint by parsing it's world space matrix or by using locators.

If you extract the world matrix of the joint using

```
worldMat =  cmds.xform(q=True, m=True, ws=True)
```

then the joint' X axis will pointing along the world vector `worldMat[0:3]`, the local Y will be `worldMat[4:7]` and the local z will be `worldMat[8:11]`.

If you want to do it graphically, create a locator, parent it to the joint 1 unit along the axis you are checking, and get its world position - the world position of the joint.

I don't think you can recover the original argument passed to the sao flag - while the joint might still be pointing that way it might not.

You can, of course,  always stash the original sao argmument in a custom attribute for later retrieval if you know you'll want it again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply!
Using the Matrix seems to get the results I want, in terms of the axis align, but it also moves the joint to the translation of the other. So I need to find a way to apply the axis change without moving the translation.

I'd also be interested to hear how you'd recommend creating a custom attribute to reference from. I think I have a general idea how to do it, but it would be great to hear your solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to align the joints in one chain to another? I'm not sure I understand the use case

Comment: I've got a script that will create joints, you can then freely orient the joints as you want. After which you then run another script which will continue creating the rest of the rig, constraints etc, but also creates another bone for the arm which I need to have the same orientation/up axis as whatever has been chosen at the beginning.

Comment: As i'm able to realign the xyz with the .jot all I need is an up vector set to the world orient of the joints in the chain, that of which has been chosen randomly at the start. As long as we get the correct up vector I should be able to run the oj=.jot part of the script above to realign as if the orient joint tool has been used.

Comment: Have you tried just parent-constraining the new joint to the old with maintainOffset set off, then deleting the constraint?

Comment: That may be a solution, although would an orient constraint be better? is there a way so that it'll only effect the parent's axis rotation and not the children?

Comment: In similar situations I usually create and align the joints independently before parenting

Comment: How would you recommend doing that, so that each joint is aligned to the next?